# Deprecated: preg_replace(): replace with preg_replace_callback but preg_replace_callback showing errors

Tags: php, preg-replace, deprecation-warning

I need a little help. Because `preg_replace` is deprecated, I have to convert all my `preg_replace` to `preg_replace_callback` when i tried to change it its always showing some error.

i have tried

Change:

```
$importedOptions = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!e', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $importedOptions);
```

To:

```
$importedOptions = preg_replace_callback(
    '!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!e',
    function() { return "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'"; },
    $importedOptions
);
```

i have tried other approaches to but did not success please help me in this

Thanks

Comment: I think the code should be something like this function($importedOptions) { return "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'";} and then no need for $importedOptions at the end

Comment: when was `preg_replace` deprecated, I think you mean the `e` flag was...

Comment: i don't know but if you can please correct the above code than its very helpful for me

Comment: is this serialized data you are trying to match looks like it.

Comment: Yes this is serialized data and when i try to unsersalized it than its showing some error about code 6 and than i found this solution but now facing this function problem

Comment: well first off you need to remove the `e` flag as I said which is the part that is deprecated / or removed, `'!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!e'` the delimiter in this Regx being the `!` oddly.  so `'!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!'`

Comment: i have tried it also but preg_replace_callback still shows error can you please change and add complete code as answer so if that works than i make it as approve answer thanks

Comment: possibly if I knew what the input was, without it I would be just guessing.